# SSIS 2005 Fuzzy grouping does not use the representative value for all grouped records

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using fuzzy grouping to find the possible duplicate addresses in my dataset. I grouped records and everything was ok until I noticed that there is a potential issue in the grouping procedure that starts around a specific record. Indeed, the procedure seems to start making several mistakes. For example, if you look at the screenshot in attachment, you will see that although the procedure recognizes the two records 15373 and 15374 in the same group, the procedure does not assign them the same PTNOME_Clean. Surprisingly, such issue starts emerging at a certain stage. Dataset ordered by column _key_out.
[image: valid HTML]